# How to get Storage size of the Application

Tags: android

How do I get the storage size of all installed applications, programmatically, which are also displayed over application's `ApplicationInfo` page?

Comment: Take a look at   http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/340f5e4f790f4511

Answer (score 0):

You could call

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

with commandLine something like `ls -l /data/app/*.apk` or `ls -l /data/app-private`

and parse the resulting data to get the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to get this information. But there is a workaround using reflection and IPackageStatsObserver. [Here](http://nsamteladze.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-apks-code-size-in-android.html) is a description of how to get code size. You can get cache size and data size in the same way.